# Intermittent Exception While Using AsyncMiddleManServlet

Tags: proxy, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, proxy-server

I am using Jetty's embedded server and AsyncMiddleManServlet to create a proxy server , which will change the response of some of the requests . For Other requests it's just a pass through server . I am getting intermittent exception and failures in this . Here's the exception stack trace

```
INFO:oejc.ResponseNotifier:qtp2046562095-29: Exception while notifying listener org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AsyncMiddleManServlet$ProxyResponseListener@606c22a1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=IDLE i=true a=null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getAsyncContext(Request.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AbstractProxyServlet.onProxyResponseFailure(AbstractProxyServlet.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AsyncMiddleManServlet$ProxyResponseListener.failed(AsyncMiddleManServlet.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.CountingCallback.failed(CountingCallback.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AsyncMiddleManServlet$ProxyResponseListener.onComplete(AsyncMiddleManServlet.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange.notifyFailureComplete(HttpExchange.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange.abort(HttpExchange.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConversation.abort(HttpConversation.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.abort(HttpRequest.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.abort(HttpDestination.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.PoolingHttpDestination$1.run(PoolingHttpDestination.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is the reason behind this ? i have set the MaxIdleTimeout , both on server configuration and ProxyServlet class .

Comment: This is actually a java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout , when the client encounters this exception the listeners are notified with this error , but in the listener it tries to get AsyncContext , and validation of this context fails . How can i increase socket time out value in ProxyServlet ?